# Adding an Role through dropdown when creating a new user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to add an Role through a dropdown menu when creating an new user. I managed to populate the dropdown with Roles using a ViewBag (maybe not the most elegant solution). But when I press create I get the following error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')

> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleName, new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles,"Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control"})

It seems like the @Html.DropDownListFor isn't passing the values from the dropdownlist when saving the form. Any help would be greatly appreciated
[image]

**AccountController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var role in roleManager.Roles)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem(){Value = role.Name, Text = role.Name});
        }

        ViewBag.Roles = list;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateUserViewModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var appUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = user.Name,
                Email = user.Email

            };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, user.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(appUser, user.RoleName);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (IdentityError error in result.Errors)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

**CreateUserViewModel.cs**

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Role")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model ViewModels.CreateUserViewModel
  
<h1>Create User</h1>

<a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
  
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleName, new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles,"Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control"})
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
        <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You will need to set the `ViewBag.Roles` in your POST action too if the view is being rendered.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick it's working now. Would you suggest to keep using the ViewBag? I feel like it brings some code duplication which can maybe be avoided

Comment: You could also pass in the list as part of your `CreateUserViewModel`

Comment: Make a method `SetViewBagRoles` and call it from both the GET and POST.  or even better, make a method `SetViewModelRoles` and add it to your view model